# Why won't these dates display correctly in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Creating a vacation rentals web app, I have a component that gets the users bookings they have made and displays them in their profile. here is the list of dates from the booking that is retrieved from the API:

```
0: "2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
1: "2021-05-02T00:00:00.000Z"
2: "2021-05-03T00:00:00.000Z"
3: "2021-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
4: "2021-05-05T00:00:00.000Z"
```

These are the correct dates so I know the database and API are all good

Now in my react app I display that dates using moment and somehow, even though the dates span May 1st to the 5th, on the UI it is displaying the dates from April 30th to May 4th. Here is the code for displaying the dates in my app:

```
{bookings.length > 0 ? (
        <Row gutter={18}>
          <Table striped bordered hover>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Number Of Guests</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            {bookings.map((booking, index) => (
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>{index}</td>
                  <td>{booking.numberOfGuests}</td>
                  <td>{moment(booking.dates[0]).format('MMM DD YYYY')}</td>
                  <td>
                    {moment(booking.dates[booking.dates.length - 1]).format(
                      'MMM DD YYYY'
                    )}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            ))}
          </Table>
```

I am quite lost.

SOLUTION EDIT:

instead of using

```
{moment(booking.dates[0]).format('MMM DD YYYY')
```

use

```
{moment.utc(booking.dates[0]).format('MMM DD YYYY')
```

Comment: probably because of timezone, if you are using moment, check about it, maybe here you can find something:
https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/timezone-offset/

Comment: Of course it's timezone problem , if you don't use that 00:00:00 hour min sec then store date in form of yyyy-mm-dd.or you have to apply currect time zone

Comment: Timezone issues are always a pain. But yeah try locking your time to a specific timezone and see if that helps.